# ListView clipping

Tags: javafx-2

i working little bit with the ListView from JavaFx2. I´m running into one issue. 
Is it possible to turn off the clipping of the ListCell/ListView? 
I add an ImageView that has to be wider than the ListView and JavaFx2 shows automatically a scrollbar.

This my code snipped how i add the ImageView to my List:

```
     list.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> param) {
            final ListCell<String> blub = new ListCell<String>() {

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (item != null) {
                        StackPane p = new StackPane();
                        Label label = new Label(item);
                        p.getChildren().addAll(img, label);
                        setGraphic(p); 
                        p.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT); 

                    }
                }
            };
            blub.setStyle("-fx-background-color:transparent");

            return blub;
        }
    });
```

Big thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible.

Maybe try to play with the Skin of the ListView. It seems that the scroll bar are managed in this class. It do not use a scroll pane.

Another solution could be replacing the ListView by a VBox in a ScrollPane.

Finally, you could try to modify `img` (by the way, where it come from, and what Class is it ?) to only show what you need.

Anyway, I'm interested by the solution you will use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I working on a solution and i will commit this here if i found a nice solution for that.